# how to iterate an array only up to where it is filled without traversing to full length

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

> I like to fill this array to only up to a[4] and want to traverse only up to 4th position not the enire length.

```
 int main()
{
    int a[10],i,j=0;
    cout<<"\nEnter 4 number :";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    while(a[j]!='\0')
    {
        cout<<a[j];
        j++;
    }

}
```

> this code prints 11 numbers

Comment: Prefer `std::vector` and `std::array` to C style arrays.

Comment: The values in `a[4]` upwards are uninitialized and indeterminate.  You can’t do it that way.

Comment: You never initialize your array to zeros so it contains random numbers. You terminating value `'\0` needs t be added by you, it won't just be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: You can't. `int` arrays have nothing like a C style string termination.

An array has a fixed size and the array can't tell how many elements that you have written to. So if you want to use an array for this, you'll have to ad code to count how many elements that you have written, i.e. by using an extra variable for counting.

Like:

```
int a[10],i,j=0;
int valid_elements = 0;
cout<<"\nEnter 4 number :";
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];
    ++valid_elements;
}
for(i=0;i<valid_elements;i++)
{
    cout<<a[i];
}
```

However, that is normally not a good approach.

A much better approach is a vector as the number of elements in a vector is dynamic. You can do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    int i, j;
    cout<<"\nEnter 4 number :";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        cin>>j;
        a.push_back(j);
    }
    for (int x : a) // Range based for loop automatic iterates all elements in the vector
    {
        cout<<x;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a special value, such as zero, to indicate the items past the end, the way `'\0'` is used in C strings, you could use your approach after initializing `a` to all zeros:

```
int a[10] = {0};
...
while (a[j]) {
    cout << a[j++];
}
```

The downside to this approach is that the end-marker becomes invalid in the input. In other words, if end-user enters a zero among the four inputs, printing will stop after printing fewer than four items.

That is why these two approaches are more common:

- **Use a dynamic container, such as `std::vector<int>`** - this approach is valid only in C++
- **Store the number of items in a separate variable** - if you must use a "raw" array, this approach is the most common.